# OpenOffice DLL CLI_UNO - Not compatible with .NET 4.0 framework

Tags: .net-4.0, libreoffice

I currently have the Cli_Uno dll which was built with version 2.0 . I have an application which is built on framework 4.0. I need to use the dll now and am unable to build the project due to the " Mixed mode assembly " error.

This essentially means the dlls in use in the project need to be of the same version. I searched everywhere but was not able to find a version of Cli_uno built on framework 4.0.

Can any one please provide me with link to where i can find one or a possible work around towards using it.

Thanks in Advance...
Prasanth.k

Answer (score 1):

Add an **app.config** to the project with the following:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/>
   </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you able to explain why this solves the OP's problem? It would increase your chances of being upvoted.